# ABAP Unit Test Classes - Good References

Tags: unit-testing, abap

I'm looking for good reference material regarding the use of ABAP Unit Test Classes.

I'm interested in any of the following:

- Documentation on the functionality
- Best Practises
- "How To Guides"
- Blogs/Books on people's experience in using test-driven development in a SAP environment, particularly what sort of scenarios leans themselves to test-driven development & how you get around the dependency of SAP on business data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some documentation in [sap.com](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/a2/8a1b602e858645b8aac1559b638ea4/content.htm).

Also, there is a German PDF ([see here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbi.offis.de%2FpublicProjectDocument%2FVortrag_DSAG2003.pdf%3FdocId%3Dtl781ldraojw%26groupId%3Dg16cglafhqva&ei=igbCSs2-Bont-Abxs_zuCw&usg=AFQjCNEoz7zdhE7vngOjkkjOfiqZXy9f3A&sig2=5pBvdlvpnRfV0DvUOEBP2A)) that may be helpful if you know some German ;-) At least it contains a few email addresses of people that may be able to help. Not sure because the PDF is from a conference in 2003, so the contact info may not be too up to date.

Lastly. there seems to be a German book ([on Amazon Germany](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3898645398?ie=UTF8&tag=smarter02-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1638&creative=19454&creativeASIN=3898645398)) .. again not sure if that helps you.

Comment: +1 for letting me earn the tumbleweed badge before answering :P Thanks, my German's not that great, but the sap help is useful.  I will try to word this question a bit better sometime.  I just find that unit testing does not seem to feature at all in many SAP projects, and I believe there is merit in at least considering it.

Answer (score 1):

There is some documentation in SE24 for class CL_AUNIT_ASSERT.  Doing a where-used on the class gives an indication of how it is meant to be used.

There also is a [5 part blog series](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/1088%3Fpage%3Dlast%26x-showcontent%3Doff) on SAP SDN

UPDATE:  There is now also an excellent course on ABAP Unit on OpenSAP.com.  It is called

> Writing Testable Code for ABAP

The URL for the course is:  https://open.sap.com/courses/wtc1

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a blog article on my experiences here: [Adopting Test Driven Development using ABAP Unit](http://www.g3it.com/blog/technical/abap/adopting-test-driven-development-using-abap-unit/)

Answer (score 1):

Wondering if you'd checked these links...

- https://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/ABAP+Unit
- https://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/ABAP+Test+and+Analysis+Tools

Thanks.