# Unit testing and SAP software

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, tdd, abap

I am looking for some tutorials and guides for unit testing on SAP platform.
So far, I have found some mention of [ABAP Unit](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_tm60/helpdata/en/94/06fc3f37c2e569e10000000a155106/content.htm) and of Ruby programming language being implemented on SAP software, making it much more interesting option for unit testing SAP software. However,  the information is quite scarce and I would appreciate some help on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just with regards to your reference to Ruby on the SAP ABAP platform, what you are referring to is "Blue Ruby". This is a project of SAP's research labs and you can find information about it on the [SAP Developer Network wiki](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/Research/BlueRuby)

In my testing a year ago, I found that Blue Ruby was much preferable to ABAPUnit in several ways, including the ability to be more true to test/behavior-driven-development principles by (for example) writing a test for a method before implementing the method.

Ruby, of course, also has far more and more mature TDD/BDD libraries than ABAP, which pretty much just has ABAPUnit and the eCATT tools. These libraries (RSpec, Cucumber, etc) seem to work under Blue Ruby. Both ABAPUnit and Blue Ruby have improved a lot since I looked in to them a year ago, but only for the better, I think.

Answer (score 4):

The [ABAP Unit Wiki](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/ABAP+Unit) on the SDN is a good place to start, as well as [this](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/ABAP+Unit+Best+Practices) ABAP Unit Best Practices article.

[SAPTechnical.com](http://www.saptechnical.com/Tutorials/OOPS/ABAPUnit/Index.htm) also has an ABAP Unit overview.

And finally, you should check out the links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402805/abap-unit-test-classes-good-references).

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent course on ABAP Unit on OpenSAP.com.  It is called

> Writing Testable Code for ABAP

The URL for the course is:  https://open.sap.com/courses/wtc1

Answer (score 0):

Detroubulator (http://www.applicon.dk/Detroubulator/) is a unit test tool for mapping programs (XML transformations) running in SAP's PI product. It's written in Java and might be considered a JUnit/Schematron hybrid.